# Diagnose File Upload Failure ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, networking, file-upload

In a ASP.NET application, users are having a hard time trying to upload files.
The application is access by about 30 people through 1Mb fiber optic dedicated line to the server.

The file upload implementation doesn't seem to have problems since the problem doesn't occur frequently only occasionally.Also i already tried to upload larger files (up to 50 Mb) and i didn't have any problem.

So i assume the problem must be on the network connection that some days must have some kind of bandwidth problem.

How can i diagnose effectively the root cause of the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fileupload module was filled with lots of try catch blocks , so the message showing on log4net log files was the error message provided by the developer. After trying step by step  to reproduce the problem we got to a part where the error message was from the system "the file cannot be saved because it excedes 50 chars", but the file was about 40 chars. The developer was using a function Server.HTMLEncode on the filename to store the name on the database but when the file had special chars the file name sometimes increased beyond the 50 chars because of the text encoding. The solution was increasing the size of the file name by some chars and when validating the file name, we validated with HTML.Encode length and warned the user to decrease the exceeding x number of chars for the file to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Do you log your exceptions? Logging modules for ASP.NET

- http://code.google.com/p/elmah/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net

If don't you can look web server eventlog.

Error may come upload limitations of web server and security problems.

Comment: We already use log4net but the log messages weren't that helpfull since one of the developers filled the fileupload module with lots of try catch blocks. Eventualy we solved it by debugging the application step by step and we found out the cause.

Comment: encoding with filename exception. i share your feelings after you solved the problem :)